# Material UI classname did not match

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I know there are a lot of answers out there but the thing in my case is

1) I already had project working perfectly fine. I took it as my boilerplate to make another one and now i have this issue of style mismatch and styles not rendering correctly.

2) It doesn't seem to be an issue on live server!

Any ideas where to look? Or what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to add the _document.jsx file i had made previously which has all the right settings to make it work. Anyone stumbling on this can just paste the following contents in a _document.jsx file inside the pages directory (create one if doesn't exist):

```
import React from 'react'
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles'
import { createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const theme = responsiveFontSizes(createMuiTheme())

class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head>
                    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
                    <meta
                        name="viewport"
                        content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"
                    />
                    <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />

                    <style jsx global>
                        {`

                        `}
                    </style>
                </Head>
                <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
    // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
    const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets()
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
            enhanceApp: App => props => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />)
        })

    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)

    return {
        ...initialProps,
        // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
        styles: [
            <React.Fragment key="styles">
                {initialProps.styles}
                {sheets.getStyleElement()}
            </React.Fragment>
        ]
    }
}

export default MyDocument
```